# Does "determination condition " make sense?

Tags: compound-nouns

I am trying to explain a flow chart.

> In step 1, a determination is made whether the temperature is above 10 degree Celsius. If **the determination condition** is met, the process proceeds to step 2 where...

After I searched on Google, I found that the word "determination condition" is commonly used by non-natives, but hardly used by natives.

I know that "**If the temperature is above 10 degree**, the process proceeds to..." is better, but I want to use such an expression as "the determination condition is met" if possible.

Comment: Actually, 'If the condition is met' would have been enough. Since one sentence immediately follows the other, it is quite clear which condition you're referring to

Comment: Yes, there is no need to repeat the word determination.

Comment: But flowcharts don't *use* plain-language explanations like that. It would simply be *Is the temperature above 10 degrees? Yes (arrow to one box). No (arrow to a different box).* In other words, the point of a flowchart is that it provides its own graphical explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just say "the condition", or "that condition". There's no need for it to have a special label.

Comment: Hm, what's the difference between a condition and a criterion?

Comment: @AntonSherwood mostly that *condition* is a more everyday word.

Comment: In some senses, yes, but in the logical sense?

Comment: @AntonSherwood The singular *criterion* is not commonly used. Lots of people only seem to use the plural. But yes, in the logical sense, people use *condition(s)* more than *criterion* and *criteria* in everyday speech, in my experience.